# Is it possible from a custom task, to programmatically alter the build project?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I have a custom task assembly, that is run BeforeBuild.

For some cs files of the original project, I generated some gen.cs files.

I want to build the gen.cs files instead of the original cs files.

Is this possible from withing the task.

Googled for it, but no hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm late to the show, but wanted to respond to your original concept.

You don't need to modify the .csproj.  In your .csproj you will see many items in @(Compile) [ItemGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx) that correspond to .cs files.

```
<Compile Include="myfile.cs" />
```

Now you have a [custom task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) that is using this as a template to generate myfile_gen.cs, which you'd want to compile instead.

Create a [target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx) that occurs [after your custom cs_gen targe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx)t which will move over the @(Compile) collection and replace members with the *_gen.cs analog.

```
<Compile Include="myfile_gen.cs" Exclude="myfile.cs" />
```

This will modify the inputs on the fly before compile time and you won't be [spinning up behind the scenes MsBuild work like is done behind the scenes with WPF and Silverlight projects](http://www.bing.com/search?q=xamlprecompile&qs=SC&pq=xaml%20recompile).

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be exactly what I need. But I am a newbie to MsBuild, could you please add some links that may guide me further?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the **Build Action** of the original **.cs** files to **Compile**, set it to something like `YourCustomAction`. Here is an example targets file showing how inputs with a build action of **Antlr4** are transformed into C# files, and those C# files are then compiled as part of the project. If you aren't using ReSharper, the patterns in this project will even provide you with seamless IntelliSense support within Visual Studio (you won't be required to build the project in order for IntelliSense to locate and process the generated files).

https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks/Antlr4.v4.0.targets

Comment: Thanks. It is half of the solution. Actually I would like that the original Build action for cs files to remain unchanged...

Answer (score 0):

I moved the task from BeforeBuild to AfterBuild. I create a copy of the csproj and I manipulate it at will and rebuild it. It is nt the most efficient solution but it works without complications.